# One-to-one model fields in admin

Tags: django, django-admin

This question has been floating around in one shape or another, but I couldn't find a definite answer to it.

Let's say I have this:

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    base_field = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class ExtendedModelA(models.Model):
    extended_field_a = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    base = models.OneToOneField(BaseModel)

class ExtendedModelB(models.Model):
    extended_field_b = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    base = models.OneToOneField(BaseModel)
```

Question is, how do I make `BaseModel` field editable in admin interface when I click on either of `ExtendedModel` instances.

I know I can reference `ExtendedModel` as inline from `Base`, but that does not make much sense to me as I want to create `ExtendedModelA/B` who "inherit" stuff from `Base`.

Googling around I found a solution on DjangoSnippets, but that doesn't work since 1.1+ and requires patch to Django which is ugly.

Is it very simple thing that everyone knows about but me, or noone does that at all??...

Comment: Have you tried with [multi-table-inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance)?

Comment: yup, that seems to work. Thank you!! Can you just post it as an answer and I'll accept it, it does exactly what I need it to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with [multi table inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance). It does what you want.